# How to associate an action or actionListener to a Primefaces submenu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to ask you if it is possible to attach **action/actionListener** NOT to a menuItem BUT TO a **submenu**, when constructing dynamically the **MenuModel** that uses a Primefaces menu (or a tieredMenu, or a panelMenu, etc).

I haven’t found anything in the w w w

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Saw your post on primefaces.org and quite a number of people have been asking for this. It apparently used to be available. One hack in earlier versions (see [code here](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2612/examples/trunk/prime-showcase/src/main/webapp/ui/menubar.xhtml)) was to use the `label` facet. I can confirm to you that that facet no longer exists\

Comment: Unfortunately, as you say, the facet-label approach seems to don't work. Thank you anyway

Comment: I have opened a new feature request: [link](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4890)

Comment: Cool. Let's hope they respond to it favourably